# "However" vs. "but"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

In the question sentence:

> He is seventy-five, he still_*_* (but, however) pays regular visits to his old mother.

Which word can be put in the blank? The answer books says "however" but it sounds quite odd to me. Can *however* be used in this discourse context, and why?

Comment: *He is seventy-five, he still but pays regular visits to his old mother*, sounds by far the stranger to me.

Comment: For that matter, *however* isn't that much better. A much better phrasing would be, "He is seventy-five, but he still pays regular visits to his old mother."

Comment: he still however pays... sounds ok to me

Comment: _But_ (like _and_ and _or_, but unlike _however_ and German _aber_) can't niche in a sentence. It's gotta come before either a clause or the remains of a deceased clause, like _It was strange but tasty_ from _It was strange but it was tasty_.

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, but I was referring to the comma splice.

Comment: I agree that commas are needed, and I think a semi-colon, too, to keep this from being a runon sentence: *He is seventy-five; he still, however, pays regular visits to his old mother.*

Comment: I venture that the OP hasn't copied the question correctly; that, or the person who originally wrote that sentence is someone who has reached level upper-intermediate.

Answer (score 2):

"However" can be used provided it's set off with commas and the comma splice is fixed somehow.

> He is seventy-five; he still, however, pays regular visits to his old mother.
>
> Though he is seventy-five, he still, however, pays regular visits to his old mother.

You can use "but" so long as you put it earlier in the sentence.

> He is seventy-five, but he still pays regular visits to his old mother.

Comment: *Though* and *however* (and *but*) are alternatives: using two is odd at best.

Answer (score -2):

He is seventy-five. Still, he still pays regular visits to his old mother.

Comment: Is this a typographical error? You are supposed to pick either "but" or "however" to fill in the blank.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but you're confusing the waters. Where is *but* or *however* in your answer?

Comment: The additional conjunction is needed because your sentence is ambiguous; it might mean *nevertheless* or *even after such a long time*.