# difference between conjunctions "but" and "however"

Tags: conjunctions

Both signal that expectations raised by the preceding statement will be confounded to some extent by the following statement.   Do they differ in any way, e.g. by the extent of the confounding they signal?

Comment: Take a look at [What is the difference between but and however?](https://www.quora.com/Diction-and-Word-Usage-What-is-the-difference-between-but-and-however). You should search the web before posting here.

Comment: related: [“However” vs. “but” — which is more formal?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141956/however-vs-but-which-is-more-formal) and [“However” vs. “but”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117117/however-vs-but)

Comment: "However" is not a conjunction; it's an adverb.

Comment: It's not that simple. The only difference between _but_ and _however_ is that _but_ is a coordinating conjunction (_but_ means _and_, plus surprise), while _however_ and its ilk are [subordinating conjunctions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/subordinatingconjunctions.pdf).  Most subordinating conjunctions are adverbial.

Comment: "But" is a coordinator (coordinating conjunction) that conveys "and" together with some further, non-propositional, meaning -- usually an adversative one. By contrast, "however" is an adverb that typically functions as a connective adjunct, as in "Ed noticed the problem; Liz, however, missed it".